# Does Pureit Polisher remove the chlorine from chlorinated water?

Tags: consumer-products, chemistry, water, chlorine

This purifier claims to produce 100% pure water. They use chlorine. [Chlorine, when taken in for a long period, is bad for health](http://www.pure-earth.com/chlorine.html).

[The 4 stage purification process.](http://www.pureitwater.com/IN/4stage-purification)

> Polisher
>   Removes chlorine and other contaminants to make water clear, odourless and great tasting.

They have claimed that they do remove chlorine from the water. Now, if this claim is false, it could be a health hazard - so, is this claim true?

Comment: Please tell me if you think I should reform the question in any way.

Comment: I would reform the question by adding a scientific reference  to support the claim that chlorinated water is bad for the health. Then you fail to find that, remove the claim :-)

Comment: Related question: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5522/do-the-water-filters-in-bobble-water-bottles-work

Comment: To be fair, I have no idea of the chlorination levels achieved inside this device - they *may* be above WHO-recommended safe levels in order to act more quickly.

Comment: @Oddthinking I'll soon add a link that chlorinated water is bad for health. I'll check out the other question too, thanks.

Comment: @Oddthinking added the link. You said: *"they may be above WHO-recommended safe levels in order to act more quickly"* Yes, but they have claimed to remove it through their technique, that's what I wanted to know about.

Comment: Your link currently isn't working for me. There are two ideas here, and I may have been confusing them. (1) That tap water chlorinated to WHO-recommended levels is dangerous in the long-term (unlikely; it might make a good Skeptics.SE question). (2) That tap water chlorinated to the (maybe very high? I have no evidence) levels used inside this device before it subsequently filters out the chlorine may be dangerous in the short- or long-term. (I have no idea whether that is true or not.)

Comment: @Oddthinking *"Your link currently isn't working for me."* Does it mean that the link is not satisfactory or  it is simply not loading? for me it is loading very fine. Secondly, my question is only about whether the polisher technique does remove the chlorine or not.

Comment: @Oddthinking "That tap water chlorinated to the (maybe very high? I have no evidence) levels used inside this device before it subsequently filters out the chlorine may be dangerous in the short- or long-term."* I am assuming that the chlorine used in this device is dangerous to health, now they have claimed to remove all the chlorine before it reaches to us. I wish to know if this is true. What may be the way to find it out with proofs? Is this a valid question on this site?

Comment: Weird. That link isn't loading from my computer in Australia, but seems to be working from a computer I can access in the UK.

Comment: Yes, I think this is a valid question here. I went through the certifications that they offer, and I couldn't see a clear statement that the labs tested for chlorine levels (although they did says that it was aesthetically acceptable and high chlorine levels give the water a bad taste.)

Comment: @Oddthinking so, what should I do now? Phone the CC there? Not sure what to ask them exactly. :(

Comment: I'd give people some time to answer. The related Bobble question was answered by explaining the standard technology used that could do what was claimed. Contacting the company for references about chlorine levels is an excellent idea.

Comment: Note: If you have such a machine, and you are still concerned, you can buy a test kit. [More info](http://www.who.int/water_sanitation_health/publications/2011/tn11_chlorine_levels_en.pdf).

Comment: @Oddthinking thanks, I do have this machine that's why the concern. Not sure if the test kit will be easily available where I live. BTW, Should I ask their CC for "written" proofs? In which way?

Answer (score 8):

Let me start off by saying it is very hard to determine what is fact and what is propaganda, since this is a water filter that competes with the biggest water filter company in India.

[Court to Decide Water Purifier Battle](http://epaper.timesofindia.com/Default/Layout/Includes/TOINEW/ArtWin.asp?From=Archive&Source=Page&Skin=TOINEW&BaseHref=TOIM/2009/10/16&ViewMode=HTML&GZ=T&PageLabel=9&EntityId=Ar00901&AppName=1)

[Pure Water, Dirty Linen](http://www.forbes.com/2009/12/08/forbes-india-water-purifier-germkill-chlorine-competition.html)

[Water purifiers ineffective in preventing waterborne diseases, revealed through RTI](http://www.moneylife.in/article/water-purifiers-ineffective-in-preventing-waterborne-diseases-revealed-through-rti/18423.html)

For those who don't know (as I didn't,)

> The Pureit water filter consists of four parts that purify the water
>   in four stages: a 'microfibre mesh', a 'compact carbon trap', a
>   'germkill processor' and a 'polisher', as branded by Hindustan
>   Unilever. For the Pureit Marvella model, the microfibre mesh has been
>   rebranded as a 'pleated filter', while the compact carbon trap has
>   been rebranded as an 'activated carbon filter', along with a prefix of
>   'unique'. The microfibre mesh functions as a sieve, filtering out
>   visible dirt. The carbon trap removes parasites and pesticides. The
>   processor is a tablet consisting of chlorine. This stage removes
>   bacteria and viruses. The polisher improves taste and clarity of water
>   and removes the residual form of chlorine from the water. These four
>   parts are collectively branded the germkill kit or the battery.
>
> This battery needs continual replacing, as indicated by a germkill
>   battery indicator visible on the front of the device. Pureit also
>   features an 'auto switch off' mechanism whereby the filter prevents
>   the flow of water following the consumption of the germkill kit. This
>   kit itself comes in various models. The model of the germkill kit
>   determines how much water it can purify before the kit needs
>   replacing.
>
> The germkill kit is designed to work at 25° C in moderately humid
>   conditions. The volume specified by the germkill battery assumes these
>   conditions. The germkill kit has an expiry date of three years from
>   the date of packaging.
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pureit

While according to Pureit,

> The first batch of water that gets purified in your new Pureit, or
>   from a new 'Germkill Kit™', should be drained away when it collects in
>   the transparent chamber. This batch of water may have a distinctive
>   taste and needs to be drained out by opening the tap. It should be
>   noted that even though the first batch of water may have a distinctive
>   taste, it is completely safe, even if accidentally ingested. Once you
>   drain away the first batch, you will get pure and great tasting water
>   in subsequent batches.
>   http://www.pureitwater.com/IN/faqs#ans19

This would suggest that at least some chlorine gets through on a new system or a new 'Germkill Kit' (ie. chlorine tablet.) However I cannot seem to find any factual information to support claims that they **don't** remove 100% of the chlorine from the water, after the initial use. This doesn't mean that they truly do, but since they have had samples of there water tested by numerous labs around the world (a result of court cases and competitive company attacks,) if they didn't in fact remove 100% of the chlorine you would think there would be a large amount of evidence showing this.

Their 'polisher' is a activated carbon filter, and activated carbon is very good at removing chlorine, and it is entirely possible for a activated carbon filter to remove 100% of chlorine from water. Most remove between 96% to 100% with the average at 99%.

HUL claims Pureit does the following:

- Meets E.P.A. germ kill criteria.
- Provides complete protection from waterborne diseases caused by germs.
- Is 'As Safe As Boiled Water'. This is also Pureit's tag line.

They also claim that it has been tested by the following institutions:

- SRL Ranbaxy Clinical Reference Laboratories, Mumbai, Maharashtra.
- Sundaram Medical Foundation, Chennai, Tamil Nadu.
- King Institute of Preventive Medicine, Chennai, Tamil Nadu.
- Indian Public Health Association, Kolkata.
- Institute of Public Health Engineers, Kolkata.
- National Institute of Cholera and Enteric Diseases, Kolkata.
- Central Food Technological Research Institute, Mysore, Karnataka.
- National Environmental Engineering Research Institute, Chennai, Tamil Nadu.
- London School of Hygiene and Tropical Medicine, UK.
- Scottish Parasite Diagnostic Laboratory, Glasgow, UK.

http://www.pureitwater.com/IN/certification

[Virological evaluation lab test results](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1365-3156.2009.02318.x/pdf), Pureit is Unit 8 (Chlorine levels not tested.)

So in conclusion, if you exclude the first batch of water produced, as the company says to do, it does seem like this unit filters out very close if not all of the chlorine it introduces in the stage before the polisher. It seems it's virus filtering ability is the most serious potential flaw in the unit, as this is the majority of the articles I read focused on.

Sorry if this wasn't very helpful, it isn't easy finding much unbiased information on the subject.

Comment: `Their 'polisher' is a activated carbon filter` Evidence for this outside wikipedia?

Answer (score 4):

I didn't see any claim for 100% pure water, as your original post indicates. Nevertheless, they clearly state that it achieves purity "comparable to boiling water." <sup>(1, 2)</sup>

The product claims to be EPA certified, <sup>(4)</sup> so it must comply with the safety levels for disinfectants, including chlorine <sup>(5)</sup>.

Nevertheless, you could contact the EPA concerning the product, or even ask Pureit for official stats concerning chlorine ppm levels and whether they are NSF *60* certified, <sup>(3)</sup> And, you can always send a sample to a lab to check it for yourself. That's the only way to be sure, except from official communication with the NSF/EPA of course.

**References**:

- (1) [Pureit FAQ](http://pureitwater.com/IN/faqs#ans6)
- (2) [National Environmental Engineering Research Institute Certificate for Pureit](http://pureitwater.com/IN/media/02Discoverpureit/04%20Certification/indian/images/Neeri.jpg)
- (3) [NSF/ANSI Standard 60: Drinking Water Treatment Chemicals and NSF/ANSI Standard 61: Drinking Water System Components](http://nsf.org/business/water_distribution/standards.asp?program=WaterDistributionSys)
- (4) [Pureit FAQ](http://pureitwater.com/SL/faqs)
- (5) [US EPA - Basic Information about Disinfectants in Drinking Water: Chloramine, Chlorine and Chlorine Dioxide](http://water.epa.gov/drink/contaminants/basicinformation/disinfectants.cfm#What%20are%20EPA%E2%80%99s%20drinking%20water%20regulations%20for%20disinfectants?)